# How do I remove/uninstall a corporate VPN?

Tags: vpn, uninstall

I have a corporate VPN installed on one of my Windows XP systems that I'd like to completely uninstall. There are no programs listed in the add/remove programs dialog matching the corporate VPN name or similar.

I can find the VPN being launched from here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Cm\<Company Name>
```

I can see the VPN connection under network connections:

```
Name                          Type                Device Name
Connection Manager
-------------------
Connection to <Company Name>  Connection Manger   WAM Miniport (PPTP)
```

Do I just need to delete the connection from Network Connections? And delete the directory? Or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the VPN is using no special software, just the standard built in VPN function of Windows.

Deleting the connection should be all that you need to do.

Comment: @Wil - thanks for the confirmation. When I deleted the connection, all the related files where automagically removed as well. Cheers!